# Printing from a Nodejs deployed Server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [this](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) node-printer to print using my Nodejs server. I have buttons in my front end which sends POST request to my Nodejs Server, where I print info if the POST request is successful. This package is a life saver and is so easy to use and setup. However, I am going to have to eventually deploy my website to Heroku or some other server. Right now since my laptop is connected to the printer I can easily print whatever I want. Is it possible to print using a website that is hosted by a cloud servers using Nodejs?

Comment: When the server is on Heroku, where do you expect the printing output to go?  Where is the printer?  At the server?  At some printing service?  On the end-user's network?

Comment: At the end user's network

Comment: It will be used by a group of people in a building

Comment: Well, I don't think you can't print from your heroku server to a printer on the end user's network unless the end-user's printer is attached to some sort of cloud service.  There will be firewalls in the way.

Comment: is there other ways to do printing? Should I try to do it directly at the front end?

Comment: Except for some new printers that have cloud service connections, printing is nearly always done from the client computer to the printer because that's where the printer connection is and is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late but the solution I use is [PrintNode](https://www.printnode.com). This gives you a REST API for your app and clients you can install on the computers that have the printers attached.

This is useful if you are in an environment where users are using hand-held devices or where speed is very important and you don't want users having to download and then print.

In the majority of cases you probably are better to simply rely on the client for printing.